# Which Power BI Visual add on download is this

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I was asked to use this Visual in Power BI. But I do not know which add-on I have to download for this Visual.

[image]

Does anyone know? If so please let me know which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a native visual named Ribbon Chart.

[image]